# How would you go about testing (to destruction) the lifespan of a microSD card?

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

I'm using microSD cards in a product and I've had some failures due to bad sectors. I've still got more SD cards from the same batch, and I was wanting to see if I could test them to destruction (i.e. till a sector wears out) and measure how much total data was written to the card before then.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple technique would be to use a secure disk erasing tool.  These tools write a sequence of data to every location on the drive.  This will test all sectors of the drive.  You can run these tools iteratively to make sure the disk is very clean.  This cleaning will use up the live of an SD card.  If you track the number of passes that run before the card fails, you will know how much data you wrote to the disk.  That said, this is best case for the drive as writes are distributed across the full disk.

Worst case would be writing over and over to the same sector until it failed.  This would result in the smallest amount of data being written before the card began to fail.  If you were to write a single file and delete it and then write it again repeatedly, this should result in premature failure of the card with the smallest amount of data written.  This assumes the card is not smart and does not remap sectors around in the flash the way that an SSD does.

Both of the above could be accomplished using the dd command in Linux, or on a Linux live CD.

Assuming the device was /dev/sdx the following should work.

```
i=0
while :
do
  dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdx bs=1024 count=1000
  if [ $? != 0 ];then break;fi
  let i=i+1
  echo $i
done
```

This is not perfect, but is about as you get without coding your own.  It will write 1MB of random data to the disk for each iteration.  When dd starts to error it will exit and you will know how many iterations passed before it failed.  The big flaw here is that the data is random.  If bits are the same as they were before, they may not be written by the flash and as such not exercised.  Assuming a perfect distribution the result will be double the actual number of writes required to fail.

A more perfect solution would involve iterating between zeros and ones or using alternating checkerboards.  Without a /dev/one device in Linux this requires a more complicated solution than I think is warranted here.